# Why use omnifaces while I am using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I need to know what the benefits of using OmniFaces would be versus PrimeFaces which I'm using at the moment.
What features does OmniFaces offer that PrimeFaces doesn't?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are different things and you can perfectly combine them.

- Omnifaces is a utility for JSF which enhances JSF itself. It's
  not intended to just provide built-in view components (even it has
  some of them), but to improve JSF standard API providing utilities as
  their own converters, filters, functions and validators. According to [its showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/):

> OmniFaces is a utility library for JSF 2 that focusses on utilities that ease everyday tasks with the standard JSF API. OmniFaces is a response to frequently recurring problems encountered during ages of professional JSF development of the JDevelopment team and from questions being asked on Stack Overflow.

- Primefaces is a library of view components for JSF. They are focused
  in helping you with already built in components which combine jQuery,
  Javascript and CSS styling. You can have a look to all of them in
  their [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/index.xhtml).

Comment: From the OmniFaces showcase: "The UI which you see on this showcase is done by PrimeFaces 6.1"

Comment: @JasperdeVries: `Please note that OmniFaces is a JSF utility library, not a JSF UI/component library. The UI which you see on this showcase is done by PrimeFaces 6.1, with a little bit of custom CSS.` I think the whole paragraph backs this answer up.