# "IllegalArgumentException: Can not set [EJB interface] field [managed bean field] to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy[some number]" with OmniFaces' @Eager

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly, omnifaces, payara

Injecting an EJB into a JSF managed bean in a multi-module Maven Java EE 7 Project fails both on Payara 4.x and 5.x as well as Glassfish 4.x and 5.x and WildFly 11.0.0.Final which makes me think that this is not a Payara/Glassfish bug as I thought initially[1].

A simple JSF backing bean in the WAR module

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@Eager
public class Init {
    @EJB
    private InitService initService;

    public Init() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        initService.init();
    }
}
```

with EJB interface in the JAR module

```
@Local
public interface InitService {

    void init();
}
```

and the implementation in the EJB module

```
@Stateless
public class DefaultInitService implements InitService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Long id = 1L;
        MyEntity myEntity0 = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);
        if(myEntity0 == null) {
            myEntity0 = new MyEntity(Long.MIN_VALUE, "myProperty");
            entityManager.persist(myEntity0);
        }
    }
}
```

fails on Payara 4.1.2.174 because of

```
WARN:   WELD-000718: No EEModuleDescriptor defined for bean archive with ID: payara-classloading-proxy-issue-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT_war.war. @Initialized and @Destroyed events for ApplicationScoped may be fired twice.
WARNUNG:   Could not instantiate eager application scoped beans. Possibly the CDI application scope is not active. This is known to be the case in certain Tomcat and Jetty based configurations.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init/initService,Local 3.x interface =richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService resolved to intra-app EJB DefaultInitService in module payara-classloading-proxy-issue-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,ejb-link=payara-classloading-proxy-issue-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#DefaultInitService,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init: Can not set richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService field richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init.initService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:185)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:140)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateBeans(EagerBeansRepository.java:135)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateApplicationScoped(EagerBeansRepository.java:105)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.instantiateApplicationScoped(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateApplicationScopedAndRegisterListenerIfNecessary(EagerBeansRepository.java:79)
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5560)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:508)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init/initService,Local 3.x interface =richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService resolved to intra-app EJB DefaultInitService in module payara-classloading-proxy-issue-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,ejb-link=payara-classloading-proxy-issue-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#DefaultInitService,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init: Can not set richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService field richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init.initService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:740)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:175)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService field richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init.initService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:688)
    ... 71 more
```

and on WildFly due to

```
04:52:16,873 WARNING [org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Could not instantiate eager application scoped beans. Possibly the CDI application scope is not active. This is known to be the case in certain Tomcat and Jetty based configurations.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService field richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init.initService to richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.InitService$$$view3
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldResourceInjection.injectMember(FieldResourceInjection.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection.injectResourceReference(AbstractResourceInjection.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectEEFields(Beans.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:140)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at richtercloud.payara.classloading.proxy.issue.jar.Init$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateBeans(EagerBeansRepository.java:135)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateApplicationScoped(EagerBeansRepository.java:105)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.instantiateApplicationScoped(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.instantiateApplicationScopedAndRegisterListenerIfNecessary(EagerBeansRepository.java:79)
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:83)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:205)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Maven dependencies of the WAR project are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>richtercloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>payara-classloading-proxy-issue-jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```

and of the JAR

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.14.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is preceeding of, but not the same as [How to use OmniFaces @Eager annotation with PrimeFaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074073/how-to-use-omnifaces-eager-annotation-with-primefaces) since in that question I didn't get any exception or other feedback even after logging was configured correctly.

An example project and GitLab CI output reproducing the issue on plain docker images can be found easily through the referenced issues (different AS on different branches and output on the corresponding CI pipeline sections)

---

[1] reported at https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2237 and https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22401 with a more reduced example which was related to proxy class cast exceptions as well, but didn't have weld involved in the stack.

Comment: `@Named` beans are CDI managed, not JSF. So adding CDI and EJB instead of jsf and java-ee would have been better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `...Proxy` class cast exception issues resulted from the Maven `compile` scope of the JAR module (containing entities and EJB interfaces next to a WEB and EJB module containing EJB implementations) in the WEB module. This causes the EJB interface classes to be loaded by different class loaders (which is correct in this Java EE setup) so that they're considered different class by definition of how class loaders work.

The issue can be avoided by changing the scope to `provided` in the WEB module without any drawback.

The feedback of application servers (GlassFish and WildFly and possibly others) is horrible as with a lot of (Java EE) technologies and I suggested improvement, although I get the point that the golden rule that if your application works correctly you've done 20% of the work and now you need to deal with the remaining 80% for useful feedback in all possible situation will take some time (meaning decades) to be realized.

Comment: I used `<scope>provided</scope>` on the Maven dependency with `<type>EJB</type>` in the `pom.xml` from the EAR project.